# How to use custom Django backend?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, authentication, backend

I'm developing an app in Django which uses an existing database with created users.
I set my database configuration parameters to a PostgreSQL server and I perform my custom queries through "connections" library.

The problem comes when I want to use my own table to authenticate users. I saw many tutorials and blog posts and I rewritten my authentication backend. But when I want to use my own table to authenticate users and set sessions, Django's Framework only allows me to use User object.

I think these object is linked to Django tables in database and when I want to authenticate an user shows me a message saying the relation "auth_user" doesn't exists. This means that User object is linked to this table.

Does there, exist some method to use my own table with Django Authentication Backend or should I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use custom Django model with existing Django login backend

> `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'`

[Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

To use custom Django authentication backend

`AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = 'myBackend'`

[Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-authentication-backends)

Comment: I've discovered it by myself, but it isn't as flexible as I want. In fact if I specify AUTH_USER_MODEL='myUser' with fields email,password.           In the database Django creates a table with fields id,last_login,email and password.                                                                                                 What I want to do is ommit id and last_login and set email as primary key.                                                          @iklinac your answer was correct but I'm trying to correct that aspect of my app. Any suggestion?